# handlebars, getting value deeper in object

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I've just started using handlebarsJS with a template and data in an object to render parts of a page (not shure if I'm using the right terminology here). I'm doing this in the following manner, here's a rough example of the template:

```
<div class="container">
{{#each key}}
    <div>
        <p>{{firstVar.key2[@index].key4}}</p>
    </div>
{{/each}}
</div>
```

The data object looks something like this:

```
var objectArray = { 
    key: [
        {
            key2: [
                {
                    key4: value,
                    key5: value
                },
                {
                    key4: value,
                    key5: value
                }
            ]
        }
        {
            key2: [
                {
                    key4: value,
                    key5: value
                },
                {
                    key4: value,
                    key5: value
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The template example I show here doesn't show the key4 value of the inner objects while iterating over objects in the first array. The first key in the array is in a variable for brevity: `var firstVar = objectArray.key[0]`. Normally you would be able to get the value I want through `firstVar.key2[0].key4`, but that doesn't work. If I do that then there is no value shown.
I there someone with experience with handlebarsJS who can shine a light? Because I am out of ideas, thanks.

**Edit:** There is a third file with a number of functions where the tamplates are compiled that is where I declare the `var firstVar = objectArray.key[0]` like variable. 
I'm not adding the actual data here because I feel that obfuscates the problem with additional data.

Comment: what is `firstVar` ? it's not part of data... looks like you just need something like `{{key2.0.key4}}`

Comment: I don't think that is a way to reach into an array, with ".0". Now if you want to reach into an object to the key named "0" then that would be the way. I think you mean key2[0].key4. But the thing is I want to get the "key4" value in all the variables in the array with the {{#each...}} construct.